# How many three digit strings can be formed from numbers in a set such that the number represented by the string is divisible by three?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set of numbers $\{0,1,2,3,...,9 \}$ , now we want the number of ways to find three digit strings such that the string is divisible by three (with repetition).

For example,

012 is a good because twelve is divisible by three

009 is good because it is also divisible by three

031 is not because it is not divisible by three

My thought was to use divisibility rules, we can find that the problem can be found equivalent to finding the number of solutions to the equation:

$$ a+b+c = 3n$$
Where $n$ is some integer and $(a,b,c)$ represents the number we picked from the set. For example, $(0,1,2)$ would mean the number 012 and that's divisible by three because

$$ 0 + 1 + 2 = 3n$$

Which is true when $n=1$

Now, a way to solve this would be to use brute force counting but I'm hoping for a better way to count using combinatronics

Comment: Note that there are four digits divisible by $3$, and three each of the forms $3k+1, 3k+2$.  It would have been easy if there were the same number of each, but as it is you need to distinguish between the cases where the first two digits sum to a multiple of three and when they do not.

Comment: Think residue classes modulo $3$ - you need three numbers from the same residue class or one from each residue class. You can use mod $3$ because it is only divisibility by $3$ which is in question. A few things to check, but simpler than brute force.

Comment: Oof I'll have to read on modular arthimetic again @MarkBennet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Split the digits up into $\{0,3,6,9\},\{1,4,7\},\{2,5,8\}$.

You must use three from the same set or one from each set.

Comment: Interesting answer but how did you come up with  this @S. Dolan?

Comment: It's really just an extension of your idea that the sum of the digits must be divisible by $3$. For this, digits like $1,4$ and $7$ are effectively the same.

Answer (score 1):

I realized a much more direct observation later, the set of strings is the set of all multiple of three between $ 0$ to $1000$

Comment: Yes. Actually $0$ to $999$ inclusive, but since $1000$ is not divisible by three it doesn't affect the answer.